# Spring Error in restful webservice

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am working with an old release of Spring `3.0.7.RELEASE` and I am
encountering the error below.  Moving to Spring `3.1.1.RELEASE` fixes
the issue.  BUT I cannot move to the new version at this time.
What can I do?

Why would spring even attempt to invoke the method anyway?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.unmodifiableMultiValueMap(Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;)Lorg/springframework/util/MultiValueMap;
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.<init>(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:280)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.build(UriComponentsBuilder.java:264)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.<init>(UriTemplate.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpUrlTemplate.<init>(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:385)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.service.impl.AuthenticatorLevelsServiceImpl.retrieve(AuthenticatorLevelsServiceImpl.java:69)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.service.impl.AuthenticatorLevelsServiceImpl.get(AuthenticatorLevelsServiceImpl.java:48)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.dao.impl.AuthenticatorLevelsDAOImpl.loadAuthenticatorLevels(AuthenticatorLevelsDAOImpl.java:26)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.dao.impl.AuthenticatorLevelsDAOImpl.get(AuthenticatorLevelsDAOImpl.java:22)
    at com.capitalone.cam.managers.impl.AuthenticationLevelManagerImpl.initialize(AuthenticationLevelManagerImpl.java:51)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.client.CapabilitiesManagerAbstract.loadManagers(CapabilitiesManagerAbstract.java:96)
    at com.capitalone.cam.core.client.CapabilitiesManagerAbstract.initialize(CapabilitiesManagerAbstract.java:56)
    at com.capitalone.cam.client.sassy.main.CamTester.main(CamTester.java:178)
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify a map at AuthenticatorLevelsServiceImpl.java:69?

Comment: That looks like spring jars version mismatch, where `HierarchicalUriComponents` (probably from spring-web) is a newer version which is attempting to call a `CollectionUtils' method (probably from spring-core) which doesn't exist.  Make sure the spring jar versions match.

Comment: As @AndrewS mentioned you have jar mess. Post your main `pom.xml`

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the documentation for the `3.0.7` ([Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/)) and for the `3.1.1` ([Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/)) you'll notice there is no method `unmodifiableMultiValueMap` for `3.0.7`.

My guess is you're using Spring components (`.jar`) with a different version number.

Specifically the `HierarchicalUriComponents` class ([Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE_to_4.0.0.M3/Spring%20Framework%203.2.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/web/util/HierarchicalUriComponents.html)) is officially available since `3.1.3`

Comment: YES! 
I saw spring-web 3.1.3.RELEASE in the build path
and added  spring-web 3.0.7.RELEASE to the pom.

Nubie Question:
Guessing there was a dependency on spring-web that Maven pulled in, even though it was not specified in the pom.

Thanks again - really appreciate it!

Comment: It's nothing, happend to me also! Mark the answer as the solution if you want.